# How to display a different component for each tree node when clicked?

Tags: angular

I am using `angular-tree-component` in an Angular 4 project. I want to display a component in the home page when clicking a node. Instead, when I click a node it displays the node component but the home page elements are gone.

This is my code in the home page component that displays the tree nodes:

```
  <div class="Tree">
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes">
  <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node let-index="index">
<a routerLink="{{node.data.name}}" routerLinkActive="active" ><span>{{ 
node.data.name }}</span></a>
  </ng-template>
</tree-root>
</div>
```

Comment: Home component is <tree-root> ?

Comment: This is part of the home component ,<tree-root> is not the selector of home component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a second `<router-outlet>` as in following example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
}


@Component({
  template: `
    <h3 class="title">Dashboard</h3>
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="users" routerLinkActive="active" >Users</a>
      <a routerLink="profile" routerLinkActive="active" >Profile</a>
    </nav>
    <hr />
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class DashboardComponent {
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <h3 class="title">Profile</h3>
  `
})
export class ProfileComponent {
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <h3 class="title">Users</h3>
  `
})
export class UsersComponent {
}
```

And define routes:

```
 {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard/users',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {


  path : 'dashboard',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  children:[
      {
       path : 'users',
       component: UsersComponent
      },
      {
       path : 'profile',
       component: ProfileComponent
      }
   ]
  }
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/4wa1bjUp058WnA8H2b7O?p=preview)**

Comment: I don't understand, why have you put all the component classes inside `app.component.ts`?

Comment: This is an example. And yes, you can do it, alltought  for a real project it's better to avoid it.

Comment: But it's not the point of my answer. The point is that you should an auxilary route.

Comment: All I had to do was add  a second `router-outlet` and children paths, thanks

Comment: Yes, the example was also for a reference and better explanation :) Great it worked!